# Doctrine ORM: Auto generate/update with relations

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

it's easy to auto-generate the models for doctrine.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities
```

Or to import it from an existing database
    php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml

But the commands generate only my mapping. It there any chance to generate the classes with the relations, too.

So that the model has the methods like.

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article") */
private $comments;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

With options like update-entities or regenerate-entities?

```
php doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities
php doctrine orm:generate-entities --regenerate-entities
```

Is there any tool for things like that? My use case is a cms where the user can generate his own data-models out of a configuration-file with ease. He should't be forced to write his own classes with the relations
(error prune for content managers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation of Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering) mentions that doctrine is only able to generate 70-80% of the mapping information. That means it cannot detect inverse associations, inheritance types, entities with foreign keys. You are required to do some additional work for that. But I agree that that would be a nice feature to have in any future doctrine versions.

My suggestion is don't always rely on doctrine's imports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony 2, you can use try the command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

Its documentation says

> Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information

I've never used it so I don't know if it's able to detect and generate relations.

Comment: Yeah, i know that comment. But it does not (as far as i know) generate the relation methods.